# Reformat Date field

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a JSON which is a list of dictionaries and I want to modify the value of the Key **dateAndTime**. Imagine I have the next JSON:

```
[
     {
        "dateAndTime": "Mar  3, 2019 11:01:28", 
        "frameNumber": "1"
     },
     {
        "dateAndTime": "Apr  25, 2021 15:01:28", 
        "frameNumber": "2"
     },
     {   
        "dateAndTime": "Sep  21, 2021 11:21:38", 
        "frameNumber": "3"
     },
     {   
        "dateAndTime": "Dec  1, 2023 11:21:38", 
        "frameNumber": "4"
     }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
     {
        "dateAndTime": "03/03/2019", 
        "frameNumber": "1"
     },
     {
        "dateAndTime": "25/04/2021", 
        "frameNumber": "2"
     },
     {   
        "dateAndTime": "21/09/2021", 
        "frameNumber": "3"
     },
     {   
        "dateAndTime": "01/12/2023", 
        "frameNumber": "4"
     }
]
```

I've made some attempts using datetime and strftime modules.

Comment: Well there are two aspects of this problem that are pretty independent. One is handling the json and the other is converting the date time. Are you expecting somebody to provide the full code for the entire problem or to answer a specific question where you are having problems? For example maybe you could provide your attempt to construct a datetime.datetime out of the input strings if that is where your trouble is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime` module. `datetime.datetime.strptime` to convert to datetime object and `datetime.datetime.strftime` to convert to required string format

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime.strptime(i.pop('dateAndTime'), "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%d/%m/%Y") , **i} for i in data]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'dateAndTime': '03/03/2019', 'frameNumber': '1'},
 {'dateAndTime': '25/04/2021', 'frameNumber': '2'},
 {'dateAndTime': '21/09/2021', 'frameNumber': '3'},
 {'dateAndTime': '01/12/2023', 'frameNumber': '4'}]
```